# Is there any (widely/commonly used) open source GraphQL library to behavior as Restful backends proxy?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, relay, apollo-server

We are trying to implement a GraphQL API which wraps the existing multiple Restful backends (say, orders.example.com/apis, catalogs.example.com/apis...). See the idea diagram next:

[image]
Is there any existing GraphQL library helping building the GraphQL server achieving this "proxy" functionality? I feel this is essentially a Relay